# Adding extra fields in hard-coded bulk-import CSV

Tags: php, arrays, json, csv, import

I have a csv file that I use to bulk import products on my site.

The current file only supports 2 fields for images. I want to upload up to x number of images.

I tried editing below code, to no avail:

```
function facncy_design_menu(){
    add_menu_page(__( 'Fancy Product CSV', 'textdomain' ), 'Fancy Product CSV','manage_options','csvimport','csv_import');
}
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'facncy_design_menu' );


function csv_import(){

global $wpdb;
$table_name = $wpdb->prefix.'fpd_products';
$table_name_views = $wpdb->prefix.'fpd_views';

 if(isset($_POST["Import"])){
    $filename=$_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];      
    if($_FILES["file"]["size"] > 0)
     {
        $file = fopen($filename, "r");
        $i=0;
        while (($getData = fgetcsv($file, 10000, ",")) !== FALSE)
        {

            $i++;
            if($i > 1){
            require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php' );
            $url = $getData[7];
            $timeout_seconds = 5;
            $temp_file = download_url( $url, $timeout_seconds );

            if ( !is_wp_error( $temp_file ) ) {
            $files_data = array(
            'name'     => basename($url), // ex: wp-header-logo.png
            'type'     => 'image/png',
            'tmp_name' => $temp_file,
            'error'    => 0,
            'size'     => filesize($temp_file),
            );

            $overrides = array(
            'test_form' => false,
            'test_size' => true,
            );

            $result = wp_handle_sideload( $files_data, $overrides );

              if ( !empty( $result['error'] ) ) {
                 // Insert any error handling here
              } else {

                 $filename  = $result['file']; 
                 $local_url = $result['url'];  
                 $type      = $result['type']; 

                }
            }

            if(!empty($getData[8])){

             $url2 = $getData[8];
             $timeout_seconds2 = 5;
             $temp_file2 = download_url( $url2, $timeout_seconds2 );

             if ( !is_wp_error( $temp_file2 ) ) {
             $files_data2 = array(
             'name'     => basename($url2), // ex: wp-header-logo.png
             'type'     => 'image/png',
             'tmp_name' => $temp_file2,
             'error'    => 0,
             'size'     => filesize($temp_file2),
             );

             $overrides2 = array(
             'test_form' => false,
             'test_size' => true,
             );

             $result2 = wp_handle_sideload( $files_data2, $overrides2 );

             if ( !empty( $result2['error'] ) ) {
            // Insert any error handling here
             } else {

             $filename2  = $result2['file']; 
             $local_url2 = $result2['url'];  
             $type2      = $result2['type']; 

             }
             }
            }

            $option_data = '{"stage_width":"500","stage_width":"500"}';
            $results =  $wpdb->insert($table_name, array( 'title' =>$getData[6] , 'options' => $option_data , 'thumbnail' => $local_url ));

            $lastInsertId = $wpdb->insert_id;
            if($results == true){
                $product_ID = wp_insert_post( array( 'post_type' => 'product', 'post_status' => 'publish', 'post_title' => $getData[0], 'post_content' => $getData[1], 'post_excerpt' => $getData[3] ) );

                if($product_ID == true){
                    $attr_val = explode("|", $getData[10]);
                    $attr_name = 'pa_'.$getData[9];
                    $attributes = array(
                        $attr_name => array(
                            'name' => $attr_name,
                            'value' =>'',
                            'is_visible' => '1',
                            'is_variation' => '1',
                            'is_taxonomy' => '1'
                        ),
                    );

                    update_post_meta( $product_ID, '_product_attributes', $attributes );
                    wp_set_object_terms( $product_ID, $attr_val, $attr_name );
                    wp_set_object_terms( $product_ID, 'variable', 'product_type', false );

                    $parent_id = $product_ID;
                    $variation = array(
                        'post_title'   => 'Product #' . $parent_id . ' Variation',
                        'post_content' => '',
                        'post_status'  => 'publish',
                        'post_parent'  => $parent_id,
                        'post_type'    => 'product_variation'
                    );
                    // The variation id
                    $variation_id = wp_insert_post( $variation );
                    // Regular Price ( you can set other data like sku and sale price here )
                    update_post_meta( $variation_id, '_regular_price', $getData[5]);
                    update_post_meta( $variation_id, '_price', $getData[5]);
                    // Assign the size and color of this variation
                    update_post_meta( $variation_id, 'attribute_pa_color', '' );
                    update_post_meta( $variation_id, 'attribute_pa_size', '' );

                    $wp_filetype = wp_check_filetype( $local_url, null );
                    $attachment_data = array(
                        'post_mime_type' => $wp_filetype['type'],
                        'post_title' => sanitize_file_name( $local_url ),
                        'post_content' => '',
                        'post_status' => 'inherit'
                    );

                    $attach_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment_data, $local_url, $product_ID );

                    set_post_thumbnail( $product_ID, $attach_id );

                    $product_category = explode(", ",$getData[4]);

                   foreach ($product_category as $key ) {
                        $term = get_term_by('name', $key, 'product_cat');
                        $termID = $term->term_id;
                        $result =  wp_set_post_terms( $product_ID, $tags = $termID, $taxonomy = 'product_cat', $append = true );
                    }

                        update_post_meta($product_ID, '_sku' ,  $getData[3]);
                        update_post_meta($product_ID, 'fpd_products', $lastInsertId);
                        update_post_meta($product_ID, 'fpd_source_type' ,  'product');
                        update_post_meta($product_ID, '_regular_price' , $getData[5]); 
                        update_post_meta($product_ID, '_price', $getData[5]);
                        // update_post_meta($product_ID, '_product_attributes', $product_attr_serial);

                        $json_data ='[{"type":"image","title":"Front","source":"'.$local_url.'","parameters":{"locked":0,"uploadZone":0,"left":250,"top":250,"scaleX":1,"scaleY":1,"angle":0,"price":0,"originX":"center","originY":"center","colors":"'.$getData[11].'","opacity":1,"removable":0,"draggable":0,"rotatable":0,"resizable":0,"zChangeable":0,"topped":0,"autoSelect":0,"uniScalingUnlockable":0,"excludeFromExport":0,"bounding_box_control":0,"boundingBoxMode":"inside","curvable":0}}]';

                        $json_results = $wpdb->insert($table_name_views, array( 'product_id' =>$lastInsertId , 'title' =>'Front', 'thumbnail' => $local_url , 'elements' => $json_data, 'view_order' => 0 , 'options' => ''));

                        if(!empty($getData[8])){

                        $json_data2 ='[{"type":"image","title":"Back","source":"'.$local_url2.'","parameters":{"locked":0,"uploadZone":0,"left":250,"top":250,"scaleX":1,"scaleY":1,"angle":0,"price":0,"originX":"center","originY":"center","colors":"'.$getData[11].'","opacity":1,"removable":0,"draggable":0,"rotatable":0,"resizable":0,"zChangeable":0,"topped":0,"autoSelect":0,"uniScalingUnlockable":0,"excludeFromExport":0,"bounding_box_control":0,"boundingBoxMode":"inside","curvable":0}}]';

                        $json_results2 = $wpdb->insert($table_name_views, array( 'product_id' =>$lastInsertId , 'title' =>'Back', 'thumbnail' => $local_url2 , 'elements' => $json_data2, 'view_order' => 0, 'options' => '' ));

                        }

                }
            }
        }
        }
        fclose($file);  
     }
}
?>

<div class="container">
<h2> Fancy Product CSV Import </h2>
<div class="panel panel-primary">
<div class="panel-body">

 <form class="form-horizontal" action="" method="post" name="upload_excel" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <fieldset>

                    <!-- Form Name -->
                    <legend>Form Name</legend>

                    <!-- File Button -->
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="filebutton">Select File</label>
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <input type="file" name="file" id="file" class="input-large">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <!-- Button -->
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="singlebutton">Import data</label>
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <button type="submit" id="submit" name="Import" class="btn btn-primary button-loading" data-loading-text="Loading...">Import</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </fieldset>
            </form>
    </div>
```